# hasura_session invocation without arguments

Tags: hasura

There is a function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.drops(cases_free_row cases_free, hasura_session json)
 RETURNS SETOF drops
 LANGUAGE sql
 STABLE
AS $function$
    SELECT *
    FROM drops d
    WHERE d.caseid = cases_free_row.id
    AND d.userid = (hasura_session ->> 'x-hasura-user-id') :: INT
$function$
```

When I try to call, I need to enter the arguments

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "extensions": {
        "path": "$.selectionSet.cases_free.drops.args",
        "code": "not-supported"
      },
      "message": "Non default arguments cannot be omitted"
    }
  ]
}
```

Is it possible to get data without entering arguments?

`Hasura v1.2.0-beta.3`

Comment: Were you able to get this working? Im sitting with same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the first args `cases_free_row` but for the second args `hasura_session` there, here's how to make it available to your function:

1. In Hasura Console go to Data, under Untracked Custom Functions, click track.
2. Your custom function will appear on left side panel, click to open
3. Then under Session argument insert `hasura_session`

Answer (score 0):

Your specific postgres function requires arguments, so no.